# xml files processing using apache pig

Tags: xml-parsing, apache-pig

I have xml file like this:

```
<CATALOG>
<CD>
<TITLE>hadoop developer</TITLE>
<ARTIST>ajay</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>india</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>ITC</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>2013</YEAR>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

and I used some regex but I don't know why am not getting desired output... My code is as follows:
    ****register /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar**

```
A = load 'input.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('CATALOG') as (x: chararray);
B = foreach A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,'<CATALOG>\n*<CD>\n<TITLE>(.*)</TITLE>\n*<ARTIST>(.*)</ARTIST>\n*<COUNTRY>(.*)</COUNTRY>\n*<COMPANY>(.*)</COMPANY>\n*<PRICE>(.*)</PRICE>\n*<YEAR>(.*)</YEAR>\n*</CD>\\n*</CATALOG>')) as (name:chararray, words:chararray);**
```

And my output is as follows:

```
2013-08-20 12:40:24,043 [main] INFO
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!

2013-08-20 12:40:24,044 [main] WARN
org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized

2013-08-20 12:40:24,047 [main] INFO
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1

2013-08-20 12:40:24,047 [main] INFO
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
```

What is wrong with it? Thank you.

Comment: @mr2ert thank you for edit, but please help me, what is wrong with me.

Comment: I just ran the script and everything worked.  You are going to have to be more specific about what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this is tested and works correct;

Create XML folder in `/user/hue/`,  and in that folder `XMLcopy catalog.xml (your code)`

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar ;

xmldata = LOAD 'XML/catalog.xml' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('CD') as(doc:chararray);

data = FOREACH xmldata GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(doc,'<CD>\\s*<TITLE>(.*)</TITLE>\\s*<AUTHOR>(.*)</AUTHOR>\\s*<COUNTRY>(.*)</COUNTRY>\\s*<COMPANY>(.*)</COMPANY>\\s*<PRICE>(.*)</PRICE>\\s*<YEAR>(.*)</YEAR>\\s*</CD>')) AS (title:chararray, author:chararray, country:chararray, company:chararray, price:chararray, year:chararray);

DESCRIBE data;

dump data;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
A = load 'input.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('CD') 
    as (x:chararray);

B = foreach A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x, 
      '<CD>\\n\\s*<TITLE>(.*)</TITLE>\\n\\s*<ARTIST>(.*)</ARTIST>\\n\\s*<COUNTRY>(.*)</COUNTRY>\\n\\s*<COMPANY>(.*)</COMPANY>\\n\\s*<PRICE>(.*)</PRICE>\\n\\s*<YEAR>(.*)</YEAR>\\n\\s*</CD>')) 
    as (title:chararray, artist:chararray, country:chararray, company:chararray, price:double, year:int);
```

Comment: expected output:  hadoop developer|ajay|india|ITC|10.90|2013 but i am getting like ()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()

Comment: That's strange because I tested it. Did you provide the exact same XML as input?

Comment: when i run your script locally there is no prob, but in case of MR mode, again facing the same issue

Comment: If it runs in local mode well, then for the same input the MR mode shouldn't fail. Did you compare the 2 inputs?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
A =  LOAD 'xml-files/cd.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('CD') as (x:chararray);

B = foreach A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,'<CD>\\s*<TITLE>(.*)</TITLE>\\s*<ARTIST>(.*)</ARTIST>\\s*<COUNTRY>(.*)</COUNTRY>\\s*<COMPANY>(.*)</COMPANY>\\s*<PRICE>(.*)</PRICE>\\s*<YEAR>(.*)</YEAR>\\s*</CD>'));
```